# A four-by-four matrix as a function of $ \omega $, but its determinant is scalar

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I have four equations that I have written in matrix form. The matrix is a function of $ \omega $. But When I extract the determinant of the matrix it turned out to be a scalar value. What is the reason for this?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Y = 2*^11;
ρ = 7850;
aa = 0.1*0.1;
Iyy = 0.1^4/12;
L1 = 4;
γ = 0.5*L1;
beta1 = 1.8751;

W1 = a1*((Cos[β*x] - 
       Cosh[β*
         x]) - (((Cos[β*L1] + 
          Cosh[β*L1])/(Sin[β*L1] + 
          Sinh[β*L1]))*(Sin[β*x] - 
         Sinh[β*x]))) /. β -> beta1/L1
W1xx = Expand[D[W1, {x, 2}]]
v1 = 0.5*Y*Iyy*Integrate[Expand[(W1xx)^2], {x, 0, L1}]
t1 = 0.5*ρ*aa*ω^2 Integrate[Expand[(W1)^2], {x, 0, L1}]


W2 = b1*((Cos[β*x] - 
       Cosh[β*
         x]) - (((Cos[β*γ] + 
          Cosh[β*γ])/(Sin[β*γ] + 
          Sinh[β*γ]))*(Sin[β*x] - 
         Sinh[β*x]))) /. β -> beta1/γ
W2xx = Expand[D[W2, {x, 2}]]
v2 = 0.5*Y*Iyy*Integrate[Expand[(W2xx)^2], {x, 0, γ}]
t2 = 0.5*ρ*
  aa*ω^2 Integrate[Expand[(W2)^2], {x, 0, γ}]

dispcon = λ1 ((W1 /. x -> L1) - (W2 /. x -> γ))
slopcon = λ2 ((D[W1, {x, 1}] /. x -> L1) - (D[W2, {x, 1}] /. 
      x -> γ))

T = t1 + t2
V = v1 + v2

Lg = (T - V) + dispcon + slopcon
var = {a1, b1, λ1, λ2}

eq = Table[D[Lg, {var[[i]], 1}], {i, 1, Length[var]}]
Rarz = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eq, var][[2]];
MatrixForm[Rarz]
MatrixRank[Rarz]
Det[Rarz]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the determinant of a square matrix be a scalar?

Comment: Of course, it can be. but the determinant of the Eigen matrix `(K-\[Omega]^2M)` is not scalar right. It is supposed to a function of the \[Omega].  But I am getting a scalar.  I am doing a simple natural frequency analysis of the system

Comment: Here is a parameter-dependent matrix whose determinant is constant:
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \omega \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$
So this phenomenon is nothing special.

Answer (score 4):

Look at your matrix:

[image]

The determinant can be calculated by the sum of the products of the  diagonals minus the sum of the products of the anti-diagonals. Now, in the diagonals w only appears in the main diagonal together with 2 zeros. And the 2 anti-diagonals containing w also contain a zero. Therefore, the determinant is a pure number. Note also, even if the determinant would contain w, it is still called a "scalar"